# UDP Datagram socket not going through and giving null error

Tags: actionscript-3, air, udp, flash-cs6, datagram

I have a UDP socket program in Action Script 3 with Adobe Air compiled in flash CS6 and I keep receiving an error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/fl_MouseClickHandler()[Untitled_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:64]

here is my code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent; 
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.net.DatagramSocket; 
import flash.utils.ByteArray; 

var datagramSocket:DatagramSocket; 

//The IP and port for this computer 
var localIP:String = iploc.text; 
var localPort:int = portloc.value; 

//The IP and port for the target computer 
var targetIP:String = ipto.text; 
var targetPort:int = portto.value; 

function DatagramSocketExample() 
{ 
    //Create the socket 
    datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(); 
    datagramSocket.addEventListener( DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, dataReceived ); 

    //Bind the socket to the local network interface and port 
    datagramSocket.bind( localPort, localIP ); 

    //Listen for incoming datagrams 
    datagramSocket.receive(); 

    //Create a message in a ByteArray 

} 

function dataReceived( event:DatagramSocketDataEvent ):void 
{ 
    //Read the data from the datagram 
    trace("Received from " + event.srcAddress + ":" + event.srcPort + "> " + 
        event.data.readUTFBytes( event.data.bytesAvailable ) );
        rcv.text = event.data.readUTFBytes( event.data.bytesAvailable )
} 



sendbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    data.writeUTFBytes(msg.text); 

    //Send the datagram message 
    datagramSocket.send( data, 0, 0, targetIP, targetPort); 

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to access a property or method on something that is suppose to be an object but is infact null. Either uninitialized or never made to an object. Have you verified that all the items in there are what they should be? I cant see where `msg` gets set so calling `.text` on it may be the issue.

Comment: Ok Msg is a text input field with text

Comment: Forgive me i dont actually do AS, these are just suggestions. Im assuming the `frame1:64` means this page line 64, also assuming you have posted the entire file line 64 is where you add the event listener. In this file i dont see where you import or declare `MouseEvent` so calling `MouseEvent.CLICK` may be your issue?

Comment: Thank you for helping Here is the mouse click                    sendbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {                                                                             }                                                                          . You are correct in assuming it is line 64; witch is                datagramSocket.send( data, 0, 0, targetIP, targetPort);              , according to every thing I've looked at this should work. but all I get is it telling me that something in the line is null

Comment: Yeah sorry like i said i dont really know AS, I would just bebug all the objects that you have in there and make sure they are set and their values are what is expected. If you find one thats not i'll bet that is your error. Sorry I couldnt be more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why? - because you haven't called the `DatagramSocketExample()` function. so it didn't setup the `addEventListener()` and `bind()` here is some stripped down test code that works. binds to localhost 127.0.0.1 and the same port so you can see it receiving the data through the `dataReceived()` event function.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var datagramSocket: DatagramSocket;
var localIP: String = "127.0.0.1";
var localPort: int = 1;
var targetIP: String = "127.0.0.1";
var targetPort: int = 1;

datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
datagramSocket.addEventListener(DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, dataReceived);
datagramSocket.bind(localPort, localIP);
datagramSocket.receive();

var data: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
data.writeUTFBytes("Test data");
datagramSocket.send(data, 0, 0, targetIP, targetPort);

function dataReceived(event: DatagramSocketDataEvent): void {
    trace("Received from " + event.srcAddress + ":" + event.srcPort + "> " + event.data.readUTFBytes(event.data.bytesAvailable));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `ipto` is a dynamic textfield set to "input text" but what is `portto`?

If it also is a dynamic textfield you should try getting the string from it and convert it to integer.

```
var targetIP:String = ipto.text; 
var targetPort:int = (int)portto.text;
```

Also be sure to check if `ipto` and `portto` is their actual instance name and not just their symbol name.

I sometimes tend to create textfields and forget to pick an instance name.

Comment: hi,  Portto is a numeric stepper. I know for sure that is their names, i just cant figure out why it keeps telling me a reference in line 67 is null when "datagramSocket.send( data, 0, 0, targetIP, targetPort);"  Data is not null, "targetIP, targetPort" are filled in, and the " 0, 0,"n is what every example says to do. I have even tried to put "data.writeUTFBytes("Test"); ", but nothing will work.